# Standard for Google Drive document format

Tags: google-drive-api

Is there a place where I can find the standard for the Google Drive "Document" format, or an API method for converting **from** it to a standard format? I'm investigating the feasibility of making a note-taking app that works in either Markdown or plain text and syncs with Google Drive. Rather than sync the raw files, it seems better to convert them to and from the Google Drive HTML format so that they can be edited with Google Drive and other integrated apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can export them to common types using the API. There are no public specs about the internal Google Docs types, however.

Please checkout our [downloading files guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads) for details.

Comment: Thanks! I somehow missed that. So I can insert and update a document converting from HTML or plain text, and download with it converted back to either. The only thing I'm really worried about after that is anything getting "lost in translation" when I want to sync changes from Drive back to my own app. If I upload-and-convert a plain text file and convert-and-download it back as plain text, can I trust that the before and after be the same, including all whitespace, etc.?